# poller metadata configuration for SFTP inbound adapter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to consumer 25 files at every minute from a SFTP directory, and process 2 files concurrently. What poller metadata and inbound synchronisation settings I should use ? Plus I need to delete those files which I have processed concurrently from my local store and SFTP directory.

Comment: I think i found the solution, max-messages-per-poll=2 and max-fetch-size=2): The adapter fetch both files and then emits each one.

Comment: So, make it as an answer to your own question or remove it altogether!

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution, max-messages-per-poll=2 and max-fetch-size=2): The adapter fetch both files and then emits each one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).